# How to convert a readable stream to a blob in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch, multipartform-data

I have a test that should read a image file and submit the image file to an api that accepts a multipart-formdata.

I am using the fetch api along with formdata class to set the image file. The formdata only accepts a blob. So in my test i must convert the the file i read in which is of type stream to a blob.

```
 test("should submit front document", async () => {

        const side = "front";
        const stream = fs.createReadStream(process.cwd() + "/test/resources/" + "id/front.jpg");
        const image = await streamToBlob(stream);
        const front = await myLibrary.document(id, side, image);
        expect(front.success).toBe(true);

    });
```

I am attempting to use a library here to convert the stream to a blob https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-to-blob. However the test is failing. If i attempt to `console.log(image)` i get the following `Blob {}`

Why is the blob empty {}?

```
async document(id, side, image) {

    const url = this.API_URL + "/document"

    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.set("image", image, "front.jpg");
    formData.set("side", side);

    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + this.API_KEY);

    const request = {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData,
        headers: headers,
    };

    try {

        const response = await fetch(url, request);
        const data = await response.json();

        return data;

    } catch (err) {
        throw err;
    }

}
```